# how to destroy instantiated objects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 3d game in unity and I made a animation that destroys a cube into pieces. but the small pieces of the cube stays in the scene and will give some performance issues later. I tried to destroy my gameobject afterward using this method:

```
public GameObject crackedObject;
// Start is called before the first frame update
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Sphere")
    {
        Instantiate(crackedObject, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Destroy(crackedObject, 3f);

    }
}
```

this code is placed on my cube. but it can't destroy the clones of my cubes after the collision. it destroys (gameobject) but not (crackedObject)

Comment: Look at https://answers.unity.com/questions/658928/how-to-destroy-an-instantiated-prefab-in-c.html

Comment: InstaniateObject = Instantiate(crackedObject...

Answer (score 4):

By storing a reference to it

```
var obj = Instantiate(crackedObject, transform.position, transform.rotation);
Destroy(gameObject);
Destroy(obj, 3f);
```

what you did is trying to destroy the original (assuming Prefab) reference which you shouldn't.